# Using regex to drop duplicated elements in columns of an R dataframe

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, subset

I have a dummy dataframe `df` which has dimensions 6 X 4.

```
df <- data.frame(
 Hits = c("Hit1", "Hit2", "Hit3", "Hit4", "Hit5", "Hit6"),
 GO = c("GO:0005634~nucleus,", "", "GO:0005737~cytoplasm,", "GO:0005634~nucleus,GO:0005737~cytoplasm,", "", 
            "GO:0005634~nucleus,GO:0005654~nucleoplasm,"),
 KEGG = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
 SMART = c("SM00394:RIIa,", "SM00394:RIIa,", "", "SM00054:EFh,", 
            "", "SM00394:RIIa,SM00239:C2,"))
```

`df` looks like this

[image]

The elements in the columns consist of two parts:

- an `identifier` (e.g. `GO:0005634~`, `SM00394:` etc.)
- a `term` (e.g. `nucleus`, `EFh` etc.)

For each column I want to retain a row if it contains atleast one `term` which is not present in any row above it. e.g. in the column `GO` rows 1 and 3 contain unique terms, so these should be retained. Row 4 contains terms which are already present in rows 1 and 3, so it should be dropped. Row 6 has one term which is not present in any row above it, hence it should also be retained.

I have been able to come up with regular expressions to extract the terms from the columns `GO` and `SMART`

```
Regex for GO: (?<=~).*?(?=,(?:GO:\\d+~|$))
Regex for SMART: (?<=:).*?(?=,(?:\\w+\\d+:|$))
```

But I'm unable to figure out a way to integrate the regex and the conditions mentioned above into a solution. The output should look like this

[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: " if it contains atleast one term which is not present in any row above it.". Are you sure ? Why the order should be a criterium ? Maybe what you want is to remove composite GO terms which are made of single GO terms which are present somewhere in the df ?

Comment: The order is important because I want to retain only the first occurrences of unique terms. For instance, in case of GO column, if rows 1 and 4 were interchanged, I would keep row 1(which has composite GO terms) and drop rows 3 and 4(as the terms in these two rows are already present in row 1 above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general approach that will handle `GO`, `SMART`, and potentially `KEGG`, though it is impossible to say without any information about `KEGG`.

The function `f` below takes as arguments

- `x`, a character vector
- `split`, the delimiter separating items in lists
- `sep`, the delimiter separating identifiers and terms within items

and returns a logical vector indexing the elements of `x` with at least one non-duplicated term.

```r
f <- function(x, split, sep) {
    l1 <- strsplit(x, split)
    tt <- sub(paste0("^[^", sep, "]*", sep), "", unlist(l1))
    l2 <- relist(duplicated(tt), l1)
    !vapply(l2, all, NA)
}
```

Applying `f` to `GO` and `SMART`:

```r
nms <- c("GO", "SMART")
l <- Map(f, x = df[nms], split = ",", sep = c("~", ":"))
l
## $GO
## [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
## 
## $SMART
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Setting to `""` elements of `GO` and `SMART` with zero non-duplicated terms, then filtering out empty rows, we obtain the desired result:

```r
df2 <- df
df2[nms] <- Map(replace, df2[nms], lapply(l, `!`), "")
df2[Reduce(`|`, l), ]
##   Hits                                         GO KEGG                    SMART
## 1 Hit1                        GO:0005634~nucleus,                 SM00394:RIIa,
## 3 Hit3                      GO:0005737~cytoplasm,                              
## 4 Hit4                                                             SM00054:EFh,
## 6 Hit6 GO:0005634~nucleus,GO:0005654~nucleoplasm,      SM00394:RIIa,SM00239:C2,
```

Comment: Thanks for the generalized solution. But I see that your output has GO terms in row 4, which shouldn't be present in the desired output. Could you fix it please?

Answer (score 1):

The following algorithm is applied to each term (GO, SMART, KEGG):

- extract the identifier+term list as comma-separated. See `stringr::str_split` etc.
- extract the term as regex
- cumulate all the terms along the dataframe as they appear
- extract the difference between each row and the row immediately preceding
- replace the string with `""` if no new term is introduced
- filter rows where not all the terms are `""`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

termred <- function(terms, rx) {
  terms |>
    stringr::str_split(",") |>
    purrr::map(stringr::str_trim) |>
    purrr::map(~{.x[.x != ""]}) |>
    purrr::map(~stringr::str_extract(.x, rx)) |>
    purrr::accumulate(union) %>%
    {mapply(setdiff, ., lag(., 1), SIMPLIFY = TRUE)} %>%
    {ifelse(sapply(., length) > 0, terms, "")}
}

df |>
  transform(GO = termred(GO, "~.*$")) |>
  transform(SMART =  termred(SMART, ":.*$")) |>
  filter(GO != "" | SMART != ""| KEGG != "")
##>  Hits                                         GO KEGG                    SMART
##>1 Hit1                        GO:0005634~nucleus,                 SM00394:RIIa,
##>2 Hit3                      GO:0005737~cytoplasm,                              
##>3 Hit4                                                             SM00054:EFh,
##>4 Hit6 GO:0005634~nucleus,GO:0005654~nucleoplasm,      SM00394:RIIa,SM00239:C2,
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort. But your output doesn't match the one that I want. Hit4 in your output has GO terms and the desired output shouldn't.

Comment: @AbhishekChowdhury You're right. The edited version should match  your expecte output.

Comment: This answer seems to assume that the identifier preceding a given term is fixed. The OP wants to filter out duplicates of `<term>`, but you are filtering out duplicates of `<identifier>~<term>`. It only happens to work in this case due to the OP's sample.

Comment: @MikaelJagan You're right. Now it should work.